# Create axes using data binding in d3

Tags: d3.js

After recently starting with the development of d3.js based visualizations I have to create a large number of axes.

I tried to use the same approach I would use when creating other svg elements (circles, lines) by binding data (containing the domain of each axis) and appending elements to the enter selection.

```
    axesSVG.selectAll("g")
        .data(dimensionExtents)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","axis")
        .call(function(d){return d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(d.scale).range(0,500))
              .orient("left")
              .ticks(20);})
        .attr("transform", "translate(function(d,i){....},0)");
```

However this approach does not work. After executing it the svg element contains only as many empty g elements as there should be axes. I suspect that the *call* does not allow the use of user specified data as for example the *attr* does.

Can anybody confirm this?

Before using an for loop based solution I would like to make sure that there isn't some stupid error or missunderstanding of basic concepts in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[selection.call](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call) works differently that most of the other selection functions.  It invokes the provided function a single time passing in the current selection as an argument.

So in your example, the `d` argument in your function is actually the enter selection containing your newly appended `g` elements.

[selection.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) is probably more what you're looking for:

```
axesSVG.selectAll("g")
    .data(dimensionExtents)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","axis")
    .each(function(d) {
        var axis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(d.scale).range(0,500))
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(20);

        axis(d3.select(this));
    });
```

Each gets invoked once per node in the selection, gets passed the datum on each node as `d` and has the current node as the `this` reference.